# If a person's score is low for a certain tag but has a high answer count, is their English "bad"?

Tags: discussion, answers

If someone has a high answer count but low score for a lot of tags, does that necessarily mean they are "slightly worse than others at English"? (Not meant to offend anyone.)

Especially for me, for most tags I have a higher answer than score count, plus I feel my English is not that good either.

Comment: 'Scores', by which I think you mean votes, are often a reflection of someone's opinion of the _quality_ of an answer, not necessarily the fluency with which it is written. In any case, this site is not a game, the object of which is to gain a high 'score'.

Comment: Just a friendly comment but I see many of your answers coming up in the low quality posts queue because, although possibly correct, they do not contain much detail or justification for what you say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can follow your train of thoughts, and there might be some truth in it, but it's also possible that a user with a lot of low-scoring answers specializes in a tag X which isn't 'popular'. Conversely, ([speaking from experience](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:18673+%5Bword-request%5D)), some tags are likely to produce Hot Network Questions. That doesn't mean that my English is better than someone who specializes in [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) questions.

And to write good answers to most questions you need to have at least *decent* English skills, but you also need to be able to put yourself in the author's shoes. Some native speakers may find that more difficult than (former) learners.

Comment: Quick point out, I'm also a native speaker, but I keep feeling that other people's english is way better than mine

Comment: @DialFrost thanks, I should have read your profile :)

Comment: What does former learners mean? Experienced people?

Comment: I meant "people who learned English as a second language in the past or are still learning (but on an advanced level, otherwise they couldn't answer questions)". It's rather ambiguous, of course, because native speakers once were learners as well (when they were young children).